# Cursor delaying results set, how to make it efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor

I have a table variable with data:

```
SiteID  DatabaseYear  CreationDate
1       2011          2012.01.01
2       2012          2012.06.06
3       2010          2010.10.10
1       2012          2012.07.07
3       2012          2012.07.27
4       2012          2012.08.31
```

In a perfect world, I want to sort the results like this:

```
SiteID  DatabaseYear  CreationDate
4       2012          2012.08.31
3       2012          2012.07.27
3       2010          2010.10.10
1       2012          2012.07.07
1       2011          2012.01.01
2       2012          2012.06.06
```

The sorting is like this: Get the site with most recent creation date and show it first (order by CreationDate desc), then get all other records for that site and show them by DatabaseYear (order by DatabaseYear desc).

Of course, the following won't work at all:

```
order by CreationDate desc, DatabaseYear desc
```

because it will apply the "CreationDate desc" on the entire result set first and then the "DatabaseYear desc".

So, I came up with a cursor which does the following:

1. get the most recent SiteID
2. put it in another table (table variable to be exact)
3. get all other records for that SiteID, in descending order by DatabaseYear
4. delete all records for that from the first table

The Problem:

This logic works well if the first table has a few thousand records, but when there are over 5000 or so, then it takes a lot longer. Since this is populating a grid on a web page, I cannot afford to let a user wait for more than 15-20 seconds. In the worst scenario (with over 40,000 records), it takes 2-3 minutes to execute.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think more in terms of sets, cursors are almost *never* the right answer.  You seem to be thinking more along the lines of an imperative programmer.

This can be done a lot more simply than it would initially appear:

```
WITH Most_Recent_Site (siteId, createdOn) as (SELECT id, MAX(createdOn)
                                              FROM Site_Data
                                              GROUP BY id)

SELECT Site_Data.id, Site_Data.createdOn
FROM Site_Data
JOIN Most_Recent_Site
ON Most_Recent_Site.siteId = Site_Data.id
ORDER BY Most_Recent_Site.createdOn DESC, Site_Data.createdOn DESC
```

I deliberately left out the 'database year' column, as it didn't appear to be adding any value.

(And I have a working [SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b2e4/4/0).)

Comment: This is great and works perfectly. I have never used WITH. Thanks a lot. SQL Fiddle is great too.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE  
(
  SiteID INT,  
  DatabaseYear INT,  
  CreationDate DATE
);

INSERT @t VALUES
(1,2011,'2012-01-01'),
(2,2012,'2012-06-06'),
(3,2010,'2010-10-10'),
(1,2012,'2012-07-07'),
(3,2012,'2012-07-27'),
(4,2012,'2012-08-31');

;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT SiteID, d = MAX(CreationDate) 
     FROM @t
     GROUP BY SiteID
)
SELECT t.SiteID, t.DatabaseYear, t.CreationDate 
FROM @t AS t
INNER JOIN x 
ON t.SiteID = x.SiteID
ORDER BY x.d DESC, t.CreationDate DESC;
```

Comment: Your answer is great and it is exactly what I needed. I wish I could mark your response as answer too. Thanks a lot.